# How to do multiple piping with select-string in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I googled but did not found what I'm looking for.

I have a big file containing list of countries and people. I am aware how to do multiple piping in Linux, but the same way did not work for me in Powershell.

This is what I looked for and got nothing:

```
Select-String .\file -pattern 'country:[ ]{8}IR' -context 5 | Select-String -pattern 'names'
```

But if I separate this command into to, like below, works (in which I want to avoid creating a file to search):

```
Select-String .\file -pattern 'country:[ ]{8}IR' -context 5 > country
Select-String .\file -patern 'names'
```

**Update 1*

Sample data after first grep is:

```
  file:1407215:names:        Hadi
  file:1407216:company:        sample
  file:1407217:city:          Tehran
  file:1407218:district:          8
  file:1407219:country:        IR
  file:1407220:admin:        Mahmoud
  file:1407221:tech:         Hamed
  file:1407222:seller:        sell@company
  file:1407223:status:         Active
  file:1407224:id:         12456
```

Comment: Give `Select-String .\file -pattern 'country:[ ]{8}IR' -context 5 |Where-Object {$_.Context.PostContext -match 'names'}` a try :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen no, it did not work:( by not working, I mean I did not see the `names`. I saw nothing.

Comment: Ahh, the `names` line is before the `country` line - try with `$_.Context.PreContext` instead of `$_.Context.PostContext`

Comment: What Mathias provided above worked for me, there is also the possibility to parse this into an object in case you want to manipulate further

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I tried with `Pre`, but the output is like `Select-String .\file -pattern 'country:[ ]{8}IR' -context 5`

Comment: Replace `Where-Object` with `ForEach-Object` to get it to output the matching pre-context lines :)

Comment: You would really benefit from parsing the file into objects. Do each entry start with name and end with id ?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I want to extract all names from Iran country. Yes, the pattern of file is the same for all people.

Answer (score 1):

`Select-String` doesn't return a `[string]` (or array of strings) but an object of type `[MatchInfo]`. The output of a MatchInfo may look like a multi line text but is split in the properties `.Context.PreContext`, `.Line` and `.Context.PostContext`. So you can't use this object directly to pipe it into `Select-String` again.

However you can cast the output to `[String]`, `-split` it at the new lines and use `Select-String` over this array:

```
$MatchInfo = Select-String $file -pattern 'country:[ ]{8}IR' -context 5
[string]$MatchInfo -split [environment]::NewLine | Select-String -pattern 'names'
```

Comment: Thanks, but but what @MathiasR.Jessen has said provides a cleaner output. Yours output is like `C:\Users\Saeed\Desktop\test\file:1407215:names:        Hadi`.

Comment: @Saeed Just make sure to check pre and post if you dont know if the second pattern is before or after.

Comment: The second pattern is always before the `country` we grep for. There's no exception for that.

Answer (score 0):

From a PowerShell perspective you will be dealing with objects most of the time, it might be a good idea to get the hang of dealing with them, hence this answer can show you an alternative to parsing your file into an array of objects which can be easily **manipulated, filtered, sorted and exported into structured data (such as Csv)**.

Supposing the **test.txt** looks similar to this:

```
names:        Hadi
company:        sample
city:          Tehran
district:          8
country:        IR
admin:        Mahmoud
tech:         Hamed
seller:        sell@company
status:         Active
id:         12456

names:        John
company:        sample
city:          Tehran
district:          8
country:        IR
admin:        Doe
tech:         Hamed
seller:        sell@company
status:         Disabled
id:         12456
```

For this particular case we can use a [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) with the `-File` parameter to read the file and the `-Regex` switch for the conditional clauses to *start capturing* and *outputting the capture data as objects*:

```
$parsed = switch -Regex -File .\test.txt {
    # line starts with "names", signal to start capturing
    '^names' {
        $startcapture = $true
        $out = [ordered]@{}
    }
    # boolean is set to `$true`, capture this line and add it to the ordered dictionary
    { $startcapture } {
        $key, $value = $_.Split(':').Trim()
        $out[$key] = $value
    }
    # line starts with "id", signal to output the object, and restart the capture boolean
    '^id' {
        $startcapture = $false
        [pscustomobject] $out
    }
}
```

After parsing the **test.txt** file with above switch, `$parsed` would look like this:

```
names company city   district country admin   tech  seller       status   id
----- ------- ----   -------- ------- -----   ----  ------       ------   --
Hadi  sample  Tehran 8        IR      Mahmoud Hamed sell@company Active   12456
John  sample  Tehran 8        IR      Doe     Hamed sell@company Disabled 12456
```

Now `$parsed` can be exported to structured data at ease with [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2) and imported back as objects with [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-7.2):

```
$parsed | Export-Csv parseddata.csv -NoTypeInformation
$csv = Import-Csv parseddata.csv
```

It can also be filtered very easily a filtering cmdlet such as [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object?view=powershell-7.2):

```
# this array of objects where the `country` property value is equal to "IR"
# AND this array of objects where the `names` property value is equal to "Hadi"
$parsed | Where-Object { $_.country -eq 'IR' -and $_.names -eq 'Hadi' }
```

Which results in:

```
names    : Hadi
company  : sample
city     : Tehran
district : 8
country  : IR
admin    : Mahmoud
tech     : Hamed
seller   : sell@company
status   : Active
id       : 12456
```

Comment: Thanks, but since it may be used in other computers and maybe by other people who do not have enough knowledge, I think it's better to do it with built-in commands in powershell. I mean I'll create a simple script for them to run and extract datas.